# Android + App Engine: Unable to create media player

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Hi I created a simple android + app engine application in Eclipse by selecting File\New then Other.  Under the Android> “App Engine connected Android project”. Did not make any code changes. When I run the application, I get the following error:

-Unable to create media player
-Failed to open ringtone content://settings/system/ringtone[image]

I googled the error, a lot of places suggested not to select "silent" ringtone in the emulator, but  the emulator does not have any other options.

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: also just so you know that picture is small and not readable. Try posting on tinypic.com and posting the image or.. just zoom in in the image and then post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the the emulator does not have any ringtones, not that I'm aware of. If you try it on an actual device, it should work.

Comment: Its not an error you will have to worry about on an actual device, its only a limitation on the emulator. Try it and see if it works.